# What's a nice way to ask your boss to pay your transportation

Tags: salary

I love my job but the transportation to work is too expensive for me so I want to ask my boss to pay for it. so what's a good and nice way to ask for it so he should give it to me? I want to do it via email.

---

I wasn't asking if I should or shouldn't ask I was asking how I should ask so I made it myself i wrote "good afternoon, I wanted to know if we could work out something towards transportation, I calculated my total income after tax and taxi's and it came out ---- please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Is your transportation expense significantly different from other people's?  And is there a reason that you want transportation paid for rather than a generic raise?  What sort of transportation do you use?  Lots of places have programs that, for example, let companies save on taxes if they subsidize public transportation.  If your job is unusual at the company in that it involves a lot of trips during the day in your personal vehicle, that's also a different question than if you're 1 of 1000 people working at an office that all have to commute in every morning.

Comment: In which country is this in? Why ask now? Did something change between the time you accepted the job and now? Are you doing an unpaid internship right now? You sound very young. If you're being severely underpaid, make sure to ask for more than you actually need because there will always be unforeseen expenses (not just transportation expenses). Besides, when negotiating, you should always for way more than you need, because you rarely get the first number you ask for.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it via email.  Serious conversations should be done in person.

That said, just ask.  "Any chance I can get travel costs for coming in to the office?"  Unless you work in an office of 2 people the chance of this is very close to zero because it would mean giving it to everyone else also.

If you think you aren't being paid your worth, feel free to just ask for a raise instead.

Comment: Nailed it. But I don’t think that asking for travel expenses to get to the office is a good idea as others might see this as favouritism and it’ll probably embarrass your manager when they have to turn you down.

Comment: In some countries it is not uncommon to cover metro or train costs (usually as a monthly commuter card).

Comment: @JonCuster In those cases, there's generally a company program -- so asking about that rather than asking about an individual exception would be the best approach.

Comment: @Boots I've seen it happen in the US. Person had their daily commute costs covered after she made some noise. Shortly after that she was encouraged to apply for a promotion to a different department, which she gladly took. Unbeknownst to her, the department was being shuttered. This type of request is highly influenced by the corporate culture and your rapport with both your boss and the company in general. In my experience, most companies consider your commute your personal expense and non-standard travel as something they may pay for or reimburse.

Comment: " Unless you work in an office of 2 people the chance of this is very close to zero because it would mean giving it to everyone else also."  That entirely depends on your location. For the past 20+ years, every employer I had either covered travel cost or provided a car (and covered the fuel bill).

Comment: @Abigail, they wouldn't have to ask for it then would they?

Comment: A few of my other workmates get something towards transportation.

Answer (score 4):

First step: Ask your manager whether there's a company program that would subsidize or discount commuting by public transit. Many US companies do offer such a program, since cities often offer an incentive to do so.

If such a discounted fare program doesn't exist, that gives you an opportunity to grumble about your transit costs and see whether your manager says "gee, that's tough", or "yeah, everyone has that problem."